# What is "critical slowing down" using MCMC for a Gibbs-Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: sampling, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, gibbs

When sampling from a probability density function of the form $$p(x)=e^{-\beta E(x)},$$ where $E$ is considered to be the energy of a system and $\beta=1/T$ is the inverse of a temperature parameter $T$, using a Markov Chain Monte Carlo method (like the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm) there is a phenomenon called "critical slowing down". It is described, for example, in section 4.6.2 of the book *The Theory of Critical Phenomena: An Introduction to the Renormalization Group* or in the paper [*Multigrid Monte Carlo method. Conceptual foundations*](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.40.2035).

Unfortunately, I don't really understand what this "critical slowing down" really is and why it is occuring when we run, for example, the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with target density $p$.

From what I read it has something to do with a "critical temperature" (while I don't understand how this temperature is exactly defined) and the autocorrelation function.

I'm not a physicist and hence would like to obtain a mathematical understanding of this problem and how it is solved.

Comment: For a random walk with a given scale, the convergence speed of the Markov chain abruptly drops when $\beta$ goes beyond a certain (critical) value as it then gets unable to escape local energy minima.

Comment: @Xi'an What do we do when this happens? Simply choose a larger $\beta$? In [this paper](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w~raananf/projects/kdm/paper.pdf), on p. 5, they describe a different solution by diving the Fourier spectrum of the estimator; but I don't get the idea behind this and why and how it works.